# How to use JSON object as variable in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, json, segue

I'm developing an Server-Client application in Xcode 4.2

The application saves some user informations and sends them in a HTTP GET request to server via server url.

As response, I have text like this:

```
2011-12-30 15:44:02.120 smartHome[340:f803] {
    button = 1;
    key = 181abc88e57c37a42769;
    message = (
        {
            ID = 1;
            date = "2011-12-10 16:00:00";
            message = asdf;
            status = 1;
            "user_id" = 2;
        }
    );
    "wrong_user" = 0;
}
```

---

(2/Jan/2012)
Sorry for such confusing edits but i haven't overcome my deal yet. I need to parse this JSON text(i think it is called text:) and do some implemetations on the results.. I have to use, for example, the message object and its status value, if status equals to 1 i will trigger a Notification in my App. As like that, if the button comes me as a value with 1 i will send a POST to the server and request for the button id and title attributes..

There are a lot of tutorials about parsing but all i saw are about Twitter or flickr APIs, unfortunately i couldnt desing a clear way to solve my problem.. I tried [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) but i faced some problems with setting up the Libraries. And if i'm not wrong, ASIHTTPRequest is not such a good idea in i-OS 5 (i m not sure about this).. Anyway, from this point can anyone please help me about how to parse the JSON above?

---

Finaly i figured out, i have done everything before, i just realized that..
for example when i tried:

```
NSString*key1=[ result objectForKey:@"key" ];
            NSString *kAndVal=[result objectForKey:@"button"];
            NSLog(@"\n%@  :  %@", key1, kAndVal);
```

i got the key and button values above.. I hope this answer will save lots of newbies like me out of trouble..

Comment: I think this question is too vague to be answered here. You're gonna have to read [key-value-coding](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html) in order to understand how Objective-C handles JSON-like objects.

Comment: I did try to solve on my own but could find no way. I m newbie in objective c so i cant be sure about the paradigm. Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should parse your JSON anwer using a JSON parser. iOS 5 has its own JSON parser. In case you want to support iOS 4 check out JSONKIT https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit

Comment: as i know this is already the parsed result. If i'm wrong please let me know and also a little  bit of guideness of how to do will be a big help for me. Thank you.